# asp.net API post values received are null from postmaster

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing a very basic asp .net api with a simple post method. The post parameters are returning null. I've tried various ways to get the method to return the object I passed in. I created a data transfer object and I've verified that the method is getting called. What else can I check ?

post master settings ----

```
     url: /api/values
     params: incidentID 4
     params: incidentTitle 'this is some text'
     Content-Type: application/json


    // POST api/values
    [Route("api/values")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]incidentDTO incid)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(incid);

    }
```

Comment: Could you add the client logic to post?

Comment: from postmaster? I'm not using any js frameworks as yet.

Comment: How does this incidentDTO class look like? I think the binder can't turn these params into your incidentDTO object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by postmaster you meant Postman.

If you are using Postman, use the following steps:

Under **Header** type **Content-Type** with a value of **application/json**

Select the **raw** tab and enter your data as follows:

```
{
    "incidentId":4,
    "incidentTitle":"this is some text"
}
```

Click on **Send**.

As the post data is being read from the body, there in no need to enter any values in **URL params**.

Comment: aha, it's returning an object now. I was passing my parameters as form data.